# Ionic app developed in xdk working in its emulator but not in browser?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, intel-xdk

Ok so where to start. First off am new to this hybrid development as well as web development so not sure whether the app i code in xdk could readily work on browser but reading through a lot many post suggest it does. 
That brings me to my problem - **Mine just doesn't!**
I downloaded two project files to help me develop my project
1. was a kitchsink seed that contained all different tools i can call in ionic and angular
2. was some sort of conference app 

As for y i took the second project which doesn't offer much of new info in sense to additional tools was the fact that
1. Project 1 was a single file project - It had all all its templates in index.html itself and only single js file
2. Where as Project 2 was quite opposite everything was modularized- Cool!
But there's where my problem starts: I got the hang of the ionic/angular framework using project 1 but implemented them using project 2's modular concept(well just dividing html and js to different files).
So now when i try building my app it just shows a white screen(is it white screen of Death! I doubt it! I'll get to that hold on).
Am stumped! My project is a standard HTML5 project from xdk, still while building i add the cordova plugin, added crosswalk still nothing. I read through a few of the WSOD article and forms one being : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/showing-blank-white-screen/15545
There's a lot going on their so many reason y a WSOD can occur, but one thing they all had in common was **their apps worked on browser!**
So now i test both Projects 1 & 2 on browser. And Guess what Project 1 runs on browser but Project 2 doesn't. That's a blow to modularization!
Now i used the inspect tool in chrome to check what was going on, what i see is
 1. The url ends with index.html#/, many other app that that work end like that too but in router url extension its suppose to be /app(well in mine it blinks and reverts back to index.html#)
2. My index file load but  stay's empty

Both point indicating that the router is to blame!But y is it that it works in xdk emulator and not in browser?

So my question is whether the problem arises due to router being unable to route modularized project or whether my routing config is at fault?

 Below is the project structure
[image]
  
But forget all that, i cut short the project so that i just load another html file to the index file

**app.js**

```
      angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic', 'ionicApp.main', 'ionicApp.login']) 
      .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) { $stateProvider

        .state('app', {
            url: "/app",
            //controller: "AppCtrl",
            templateUrl: "templates/splash.html"

        });




    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('app');
})
```

**index.html**

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html ng-app="ionicApp">
         <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
             <meta name="viewport"  content="initial-scale=1,  maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
             <title></title>

             <link href="lib/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

              <script src="lib/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
              <script src="lib/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>


               <script src="lib/angular-toastr.tpls.min.js"></script>
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/angular-toastr.min.css" />

        <!-- your app's js -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
          <script src="js/main.js"></script>
          <script src="auth/login.js"></script>

       <style>

       .box {height:300px;padding: 10px}

     </style> 
     </head>

      <body >
         <div>Helllo!</div>
        <ion-nav-view>
         </ion-nav-view>
         </body>
      </html>
```

**splash.html**

```
      <ion-view >bye!!!</ion-view>
```

And thats it this shows up in the xdk emulator but not on browser(forget building it!). Oh and take close notice to the routing file i tried
1. putting ';' after .state()
2. '/app' in otherwise()
3. removing '/' from '/app' in both places
and what else..... in short i tried a lot of stuff yet nothing. Just saying!

Oh one more thing i downloaded latest lib file cause the ones packed with xdk where causing trouble even within its emulator!

Any help is truely appriciated!
Thank you!

## Update

Ok so now i tried making the an inline call to a template same routing code and everything just add a

```
<script id="about.html" type="text/ng-template">
 <div >About!!</div>
```

within the index.html and made templateurl of state app about.html and vola it works!
So Bad news to guys who prefer modular coding coz i think xdk won't allow that!
If anyone finds a workaround PLEASE Help me!
I just don't won't to write a huge monolithic code!
Thank you!

## Update-2

Check this Plunker page by 'scotch.io' : http://plnkr.co/edit/dd8Nk9PDFotCQu4yrnDg?p=preview 
    They too using multiple pages so i tried this code on my system this too was to no avail! The area that loads the templates stays empty. So i think it must be a problem with my system!

So i have the xdk installed and i also have the ionic cli installed but never used it don't know if it would interfere with xdk, but its there.
do i need to install anything else?
Thank you!

## Update-3

This is funny! The code i refered to through plunker works on xdk emulator, but doesn't work on browser! Then just for the sake of it put all the referring css file and js files into the lib folder and built it. And it works on my android device! **Weird!** 
Oh and also this code uses angular-router rather than ui-router.
Hope it helps narrow down the possible culprits.
Thank you!

## Update-4

Ok so i got my app running. There seems to be an issue in one of the ionic library, coz to get my app working i had to call the angular-ui-router script and inject the ui-router dependency into the angular module. but still it doesn't work on the browser.
Now it makes me wonder how ionic works and what exactly ionic is?(Framework, library, something else?)

Comment: can you summarize your question? There is too much details.

Comment: hmmm, issue in routing, works in emulator not browser, cause maybe wrong lib file for routing, Help!!!??

Comment: i don't know how else to summarize it! theirs a lot of reason y am getting this, and as am new to this its concepts aren't very clear to me to be more specific about my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using your terminal/cmd to run it in the browser? If not go into terminal and cd into your app and run "ionic serve --lab" this will spin up both ios and android in your default browser.

Comment: But am not using ionic severs! Am coding in XDK and also building it via XDK. Also like i mentioned above one of the projects readily runs on the browser ( Click and drag to browser) but not mine!

Comment: if you are building an app through Ionic the browser view really shouldn't be used for testing anyway. You should really just be using an emulator as it will provide the most accurate testing. Is there a reason why you need to run a browser view of this opposed to just using an emulator? Ionic isn't made for building websites, primarily only mobile applications

Comment: I agree. But having said that the said issues where caused by broken library files provided by XDK. So what i saw in XDK emulator was not what i got in the android emulator! That's why i thought to check it out on the browser. And that's all. But after seeing such a unique outcomes(some apps working and others not) i got a bit curious as to why that's all. Oh And i was able to solve most of the issue by just downloading ionic and angular lib files separately and not relying on the ones provided by XDK! If ever you or me find the reason as to why, lets update it! ;) Cheers!